# redirect_to current_user with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I pass parameters to my current_user redirect?

```
# SessionHelper.rb
def current_user
    if(user_id  = session[:user_id]) 
        @current_user ||= User.find(user_id)
    else
        @current_user = nil
    end
end

#SomeController.rb
def some_action
   redirect_to current_user, param1: "bubbles"
end

# routes.rb
resources :doctors, :admins, :agencies # this is the line that handles current_user path
```

Such as resulting URL would be like foo.com/?param1='bubbles'. The confusing thing here is, I use STI for different types of users, so every user type has its own **'show'** url, so a approach like this

```
redirect_to controller: 'thing', action: 'edit', id: 3, something: 'else'
```

would not work, since every user type has its own controller.

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: @RichPeck updated the question.

Comment: What's the other `param` you're trying to pass? If it's the same for all the controllers, why not create some common functionality for it?

Comment: @RichPeck, yes, it is the same. However, the user must be on a particular page to do that action, with the parameters passed from SomeController. Actual system is, I have a notification box in header. When user clicks it from any page, it goes to the home page and loads a user-specific information dynamically in that page. That is why I pass params, so the browser knows from which url it must request user-specific information

Comment: Try `redirect_to current_user, params: {something: "value"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
redirect_to  polymorphic_path(current_user, something:'else')
```

Comment: @BurakÖzmen are these `nil`? params without value are not appended to path

Comment: Nope, I am sure they are not nil but, I'll give it another try.